# Is there such a thing as an "Always" loop?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide

I seem to remember somewhere somebody making an "Always" loop between Setup() and Loop().

But I can't find any documentation on it. Does such a thing exist, or am I imagining it?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing officially called an "always" loops as such. However, you can make a loop which goes on forever like this:

```
while (true)
{
    // this bit repeats forever
}
```

A `while` loop checks the condition before every iteration of the main body. If it detects that the condition equals boolean `false` then it will stop the loop and move on to the next bit of code.

Normally, the condition would be some kind of expression, like `(x < 10)`. However, in the example above, the condition is hard-coded as `true`, meaning it will never be `false` so it will never stop.

Comment: Another variant - with exactly the same result - is `for(;;){ ... }`, which appeals to me for the simple reason that it reads almost like the word "forever". (Or maybe I just have an overactive imagination.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be thinking of the *Serial Event* system.

This is a specially defined function which runs whenever `loop()` finishes *if there is anything to read from the serial port*.

- http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent

Basically it is implemented as a function call after `loop()` in the `main()` function, which looks like this:

```
setup();

for (;;) {
    loop();
    if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
}
```

As you can see there is only `setup()`, `loop()` and the *serial event* system.

Comment: serialEventRun is a weak reference. If some code file (typically an included library) defines a function by that name, it is called. It really does not check for serial data, but that is what it could be used for. The name only hints at a purpose, but nothing really ties it to serial data ready (despite misleading documentation).

Comment: @Spiked3 I beg to differ.  Yes, it is defined as weak, but *there is a default one provided in HardwareSerial.cpp:190 which checks for serial data availability*.  Yes, you can override it with your own, but if you don't (and few would) then it acts exactly as I described.

Comment: Interesting. We must have different code, as I am looking and the line you mention is at 63, not 190, but it is preceded with a note '// this next line disables the entire HardwareSerial.cpp, 
// this is so I can support Attiny series and any other chip without a uart". In any case, in context of this question, not important, your answer stands as correct.